# How to extend class<T extends class>

Tags: java, class

I want to extend a Class that already has `<T extends class>` in it.
For example, I want to extend this class named Foo:

```
    public class Foo<T extends OtherClass>{

    }
```

How do I do this?
I tried this but it is not working:

```
    public class MyClass<T extends OtherClass> extends Foo{

    }
```

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Your code is full of mistakes. Please make an effort to present clean, formatted code when asking a question. And try to follow Java naming conventions, such as classes beginning with uppercase.

Comment: sorry , i corrected them :)

Comment: Corrected? `extands` is still wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is

```
public class MyClass<T extends OtherClass> extends Foo<T> {
```

If you want to extend it with a specific type of `T`:

```
public class MyClass extends Foo<Bar> {
```

Answer (score 1):

See:

```
public class Foo<T extends OtherClass> {

}

public class MyClass<T extends OtherClass> extends Foo<T> {

}
```

Comment: Your welcome. Please mark the answer as the correct.